# in R: Setting new Values in a data.table fast

Tags: r, data.table

I am trying to set values to a data.table in an efficient way. The following code will do what I want, but it is too slow for large datasets:

```
DTcars<-as.data.table(mtcars)
for(i in 1:(dim(DTcars)[1]-1)){
  for(j in 1:dim(DTcars)[2]){
    if(DTcars[i,j, with=F]>10){
      set(DTcars,
          i=as.integer(i),
          j =as.integer(j)  ,
          value = DTcars[dim(DTcars)[1],j,with=F])
    }
  }
}
```

And I want something like this... which is totally a wrong code, but expresses my need and I think it would be faster. Meaning that I want to subset my data.table and insert the same value for a particular column and repeat for each column.

```
DTcars<-as.data.table(mtcars)
ns<-names(DTcars)
for(j in 1:length(ns)){
  DTcars[ns[j]>10]<-DTcars[20,ns[j]]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMO `set` should be used sparingly, and regular `:=` is sufficient almost always:

```
for (col in names(DTcars))
  DTcars[get(col) > 10, (col) := get(col)[.N]]
```

Comment: Yeah, this solution is even better I think... I was going to put in the title "without using set"

Comment: I don't see any advantage over `set` except perhaps aesthetically (sticking with the familiar `[`)..?

Comment: @eddi I see none of that here, so perhaps your reasons are subjective (which is fine).

Comment: @Frank uhh... readability - it's shorter, doesn't contain DTcars multiple times; the latter makes it more maintainable if you need to change smth, it's also much easier to fiddle with conditions on RHS of `j` (as well as conditions in `i`); the non-repetitiveness also makes the code more robust against typos; finally it's far more extensible - a simple case is changing circumstances requiring a `by`

Answer (score 3):

I think you're looking for

```
for (j in names(DTcars)) set(DTcars,
  i     = which(DTcars[[j]]>10),
  j     = j,
  value = tail(DTcars[[j]],1)
)
```

The column numbers or names can be used as the `for` iterator here.

The `value` changes between the two pieces of code in the OP, so I'm not sure about that.

Comment: Yes, that is the answer... Awesome :)